# Using knockoutjs with replaced form elements

Tags: knockout.js

I have a website with the design done already that I am trying to integrate with Knockout.js Instead of having your normal `<input type="checkbox">`, the UI has some jQuery code that replaces all the checkboxes with a `<span>` that is rigged up with images to behave like a normal checkbox.

What would be the best way to bind to this dynamically added `<span>` and use it like a normal checkbox?

Here is a jsfiddle of the code that I have: http://jsfiddle.net/Fw28P/

Comment: why are you replacing your check boxes with the spans? why not use them directly in your HTMl ?

Comment: this is a simple example. For scroll boxes they want the UI to look like something that a jQuery plugin provides, and that one is very complicated, so I thought this was a better example to show in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the jQuery logic in a custom binding

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Comment: How would one go about doing that? The <label> tag should toggle the quasi checkbox as well.

Comment: Your binding could add a unique id to the checkbox and then insert a label with the for attribute set to that id. That what I did with my label binding for this binding collection https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings For a demo http://jsfiddle.net/93xRH/